# Running consecutive commands with python fabric module

Tags: python, fabric

I am writing an application that interacts with numerous systems, specifically with switches,

i am trying to implement a function that will enable me to retreive logs from a specific switch using Fabric (python)

in a real session to the switch i would need to first run "enable" (and press enter key) and then run "debug generate dump" command.

using fabric.operations.run() i can only issue one command at a time,
using fabric.operations.open_shell() is not an option since i need to parse the output and also close the connection once it finishes.

Can someone assist on this?
THANKS!!

Here is an example of the code:

```
def getSwitchLog(self, host, port, username, password):
        env.host_string = "%s:%s" % (host, port)
        env.user = username
        env.password = password
        command = 'enable \r debug generate dump'
        run(command, shell=cli, pty=True, combine_stderr=True, timeout=120)
```

- shell=cli - because the switch does not run bash and 'cli' is the appropriate value in this case
- \r should have sent "enter" key essentially sending 1. enable 2. enter 3. debug generate dump
- this method works if i switch run with open_shell
  but it seems run ignores \r

I was able to achieve what i need using:

```
command = 'sshpass -p admin ssh admin@switchIP cli \"enable\" \"show version\"'
fabric.api.local(command, capture=True, shell=None)
```

however this method is not robust as fabric.api.run() and also requires the running node to have sshpass installed

This is an example of the output from the switch CLI as the commands entered interactively (keyboard) without fabric

```
[standalone: master] > enable
[standalone: master] # debug generate dump
[standalone: master] # debug generate dump Generated dump sysdump-SX6036-1-20130630-104051.tgz
[standalone: master] #
```

thanks.

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Hi greg, thanks for your comment, i have updated the description and it now contains the code example.

Comment: so you have to input something in bash on the remote box after you run some kind of cmd?

Comment: I don't understand... why not just use the [put](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/operations.html) operation..

Comment: Hi Greg, the remote box is a switch, which runs a propietry shell, the generate dump command creates a tarball on the switch which later on i am going to pull, the output of the generate dump command is the filename i need to pull, the problem is, i can't run generate dump without entering to "enable" mode first, that means that in one remote session i need to first run run the command "enable" and only then the command "debug generate dump" i will upload a screen shot of what it looks like in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So working with a session state isn't something Fabric does. Every call is a new session. There are some other project that try and get around this, one being fexpect, but since you're  attempting to query a switch I don't believe that will work. Since fexpect (last i knew) uploads a expect script which it then runs to the remote machine.

What you might have better luck with though is [pxssh from the pexpect module](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pxssh.html#pxssh). It allows ssh+expect like work simple enough. It's outside Fabric, but more likely to work for you right out of the gate I think.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i went with pure Paramiko eventually.

Answer (score -1):

work with robot-framework based on 'paramiko'. It has more simple API (write/read_unitl/read_all) to interact with your switch shell.

http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html